# How to pull filtered Data from a Datatable and create a string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a dataset **ds** with two fields, **AllowInput** *int* and **TypeName** *string*.
I wanna get all TypeName as a comma separated string where AllowInput == 1

This is what I have done so far.

```
string keys = string.Join(",", ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().
                Where(x => x["AllowInput"].ToString() == "1").
                ToArray().
                Cast<DataRow>().
                Select(x => x["TypeName"].ToString()).
                ToArray());
```

This works.
But does the code needs to be this verbose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably drop the following 2 lines:

```
            ToArray().
            Cast<DataRow>().
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using the [DataRow extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx) defined in Linq to DataSet

Something like:

```
string keys = string.Join(",", from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                               where (row.Field<int>("AllowInput") == 1)
                               select row.Field<string>("TypeName"));
```